# How to save selected checkbox values and get it as checked when we move to the next page and come back to checkbox page

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

i have an report query having checkbox column, here when we checked some value and sumbiteed it will move on next page and in second page there is an option to go back, when i click on go back button it has to checked the value which is previously checked and show as checked.

how to work on this in apex

my report query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT APEX_ITEM.checkbox (1, ASSOCIATED_PARTY_ID) Select_Checkbox,
                FIRST_NAME || LAST_NAME AS Associated_Party,
                EMAIL AS Associated_Party_Email,
                associated_party_id,
                EMPLOYMENT_STATUS,
                LOCATION AS Current_Location,
                CITY || STATE_PROVISION AS City_State_Provision,
                MANAGER
  FROM ASSOCIATED_PARTIES
 WHERE associated_party_id IN (SELECT associated_party_id
                                 FROM matters_associated_parties
                                WHERE matter_id = :P10_MATTER_ID);
```

Comment: If the checkbox is submitted (as you said), then it should remain *checked* when you return back to that page so ... you shouldn't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the selected checkboxes (ASSOCIATED_PARTY_ID) in a Apex_collection when u go foward.

If the user goes back you can load the selected ones from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

if you are go to another page and come back to old page the selection will be there. p_checked_values =>:p604_blc_id its a apex item it will store the accociated_party_id

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        <pre>
        apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx => 1,
        p_value => blc.blc_id,
        p_attributes => 'class="blc_id" id="f01_'|| rownum|| '"',
        p_checked_values =>:p604_blc_id,
        p_checked_values_delimiter => ',')"Select All",


        <input type="checkbox" onclick="$f_CheckFirstColumn(this)" id="check_all"/>




        // Created by parthiban on 11-5-2016

        var
        //Checkbox that was changed
        $checkBox = $(this.triggeringElement),
        //DOM object for APEX Item that holds list.
        apexItemIDList = apex.item(this.affectedElements.get(0)),
        //Convert comma list into an array or blank array
        //Note: Not sure about the "?" syntax see: http://www.talkapex.com/2009/07/javascript-if-else.html
        ids = apexItemIDList.getValue().length === 0 ? [] : apexItemIDList.getValue().split(','),
        //Index of current ID. If it's not in array, value will be -1
        idIndex = ids.indexOf($checkBox.val())
        ;

        //If box is checked and it doesn't already exist in list
        if ($checkBox.is(':checked') && idIndex < 0) {
        ids.push($checkBox.val());
        }
        //If box is unchecked and it exists in list
        else if (!$checkBox.is(':checked') && idIndex >= 0){
        ids.splice(idIndex, 1);
        }

        //Convert array back to comma delimited list
        apexItemIDList.setValue(ids.join(','));

        </pre>
```